# Allow non-admins to reboot remote computer

Tags: windows, shutdown, reboot, remote, non-admin

### Description of Problem

We have some kiosks (running Windows 7) at some of our stores that have software on them that error out occasionally. The fix is to simply reboot these kiosks and they work again - the only problems is that since they are touch screens and it's difficult to connect an external mouse and keyboard to them, the users at the store always call the help desk to reboot them remotely.

### Proposed Resolution / Question

These users aren't admins, but I would like either an app or a simple batch file that the users could run and it'd initiate a restart as a service account that is on the kiosks. The problem is that I don't believe .bat files support runas in one line without prompting for a password (whenever I tested it). I figured this may be something that has a resolution already that I may be missing. If there is an application that exists that could also perform this task, I'd be open to suggestions.

Comment: Create a scheduled task that looks for a file or marker every minute. When the file or marker is found, trigger the restart and reset the trigger file or marker. This task can run pre-configured with sufficient rights, and the file or marker can be something that can be placed by people with user-level permissions.

Comment: Kiosk mode is a very specific description for Windows 8+ it means a certain type of application is running.  However, on Windows 7, it means third-party.  In either case anything not specifically allowed isn’t possible.  Due to massive differences this question as written cannot be answered.  How you accomplish this on Windows 7 with a third-part Kisok Program is entirely different then Kisok mode on Windows 8+

Comment: Are the kiosk computers in the same domain as the computer from which the users would initiate the reboot?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator That is correct. They are all on the domain.